# Facebook GRAPH API, php SDK problem

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

it's weird this morning all my facebook applications don't work anymore. And when I use the graph API using request like : "graph.facebook.com/me" 
I got :

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
   }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook did a developer update the past couple days..

> http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/518/

We had problems with the API key on older versions of the sdk, check that.

Comment: if you click on where it says 'n minutes ago' it will show you what was changed

Answer (score 1):

same thing here. I followed Ben Biddington's [blog](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/) to get the access token. Same error when trying to use it. Facebook's OAuth implementation doesn't follow the spec completely, i am fine with it as long as the doc is clear, which obviously is not the case here. Aslo, it would be nice if the userid and username are returned with the access token.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an app so that you can get an appId and secret. Then you can create a facebook object like so:

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $appId,
    'secret' => $secret,
    'cookie' => $cookie
));
```

and get the access token with `$fb->getAccessToken();` this can then be appended to your graph api call url, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

when you click on facebook button, after login one cookie is generated with fbs_(token_access). by which  it understands that you are logged in. may be because you are going directly you dont have sufficient access to get json encoded data..

this can be the problem for you.. make sure when you are loggedd in,cookie is generated ..

Comment: Thanks for all answers. but I don't understand, why all my app break this morning and not before.

Answer (score 0):

As the message states, you need to provide a valid access token. If you aren't providing one, then it obviously is the problem, as you need to have one, even when accessing your own information. If you are providing one, and it gives that error, then the token is not valid, which may be because it has expired or been revoked.